# IBM Connections API - How to attach files to wiki pages?

Tags: ibm-connections

In the IBM Connections user interface, it's possible to attach files directly to wiki pages.
I want to attach files to wiki pages programatically, but can't find a documented way to do so.

I've been looking at the Connections 4.5 API documentation here:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.5+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&content=catcontent&ct=prodDoc

Looking specifically at the APIs for Files and Wikis, there seems to be nothing about wiki-page attachments. While I'm mainly looking to upload attachments, I can't even see a documented API to retrieve attachments, despite the user-interface having a link to a feed (on each wiki page) that does that.

Is there any (possibly undocumented) API to attach files to a wiki page?

Comment: I am looking at the API now.  I'll post a response when I am done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some sample code to show how to do it in a supported way.

First, you need two URLs.

```
private static String apiUrlWikiNonce = "https://sdkdev.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/wikis/basic/api/nonce";
private static String apiUrlWikiAttachment = "https://sdkdev.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/wikis/form/api/wiki/{WIKI_LABEL_OR_WIKI_UUID}/page/{PAGE_LABEL_OR_PAGE_UUID}/feed";
```

Get the Nonce

```
   /**
     * gets the nonce value only valid return type is text, anything else throws
     * an error
     * 
     * @param httpClient
     * @param user
     * @param password
     * @return
     */
    public static String getNonce(CloseableHttpClient httpClient, String user,
            String password) {
        String result = "";
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(apiUrlWikiNonce);

        String combo = user + ":" + password;
        String hash = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
                .encodeBase64String(combo.getBytes());
        System.out.println(user + " is logging in with " + hash);
        String auth = "Basic " + hash;
        httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", auth.replace("=", ""));

        HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();

        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
        try {

            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, context);

            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

            IOUtils.copy(is, writer);
            String responseString = writer.toString();
            // System.out.println(responseString);

            result = responseString;

            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                response.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Now that you have the nonce such as... b1911872-36f1-4767-956d-214759886406

Then upload a file with X-Update-Nonce

```
/**
     * uploads a file to a given wiki page.
     * 
     * @param httpClient
     * @param user
     * @param password
     * @param wikiLabel
     * @param wikiPage
     * @param file
     * @param nonce
     * @return uuid <empty or uuid of file>
     */
    public static String uploadFileToWiki(CloseableHttpClient httpClient, String user,
            String password, String wikiLabel, String wikiPage, File file, String nonce){
        String uuid = "";

        String apiUrl = apiUrlWikiAttachment.replace("{WIKI_LABEL_OR_WIKI_UUID}", wikiLabel);
        apiUrl = apiUrl.replace("{PAGE_LABEL_OR_PAGE_UUID}", wikiPage);

        //Mandatory Parameter
        apiUrl += "?category=attachment";


        System.out.println("API Url : " + apiUrl);

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(apiUrl);
        post.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0");
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");

        String combo = user + ":" + password;
        String hash = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
                .encodeBase64String(combo.getBytes());
        System.out.println(user + " is logging in with " + hash);
        String auth = "Basic " + hash;
        post.setHeader("Authorization", auth.replace("=", ""));

        HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();

        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            EntityBuilder builder = EntityBuilder.create();
            builder.setFile(file);
            HttpEntity postentity = builder.build();

            post.setHeader("Slug","NominalWorkItem-v1.png");
            post.setHeader("title","Test Title");
            post.setHeader("label","Test Test");

            post.setEntity(postentity);

            response = httpClient.execute(post, context);

            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

            IOUtils.copy(is, writer);
            String responseString = writer.toString();
            System.out.println(responseString);

            uuid = responseString;

            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                response.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        return uuid;
    }
```

The file is updated, and you get the response code 201 when created, and the XML

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry
> xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0"
> xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"
> xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn" xmlns:td="urn:ibm.com/td"
> xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><id>urn:lsid:ibm.com:td:7780e11c-7240-41b3-8f0c-00a10ea69c93</id><td:uuid>7780e11c-7240-41b3-8f0c-00a10ea69c93</td:uuid><td:label>NominalWorkItem-v1.png</td:label><link
> href="https://sdkdev.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/wikis/form/api/wiki/744ccaeb-e9af-434c-9fa6-78831fb94846/page/3b017473-2dbe-4920-85a2-bf908a8e1475/attachment/7780e11c-7240-41b3-8f0c-00a10ea69c93/entry"
> rel="self"></link><link
> href="https://sdkdev.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/wikis/form/anonymous/api/wiki/744ccaeb-e9af-434c-9fa6-78831fb94846/page/3b017473-2dbe-4920-85a2-bf908a8e1475/attachment/7780e11c-7240-41b3-8f0c-00a10ea69c93/media/NominalWorkItem-v1.png"
> rel="alternate"></link><link
> href="https://sdkdev.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/wikis/form/api/wiki/744ccaeb-e9af-434c-9fa6-78831fb94846/page/3b017473-2dbe-4920-85a2-bf908a8e1475/attachment/7780e11c-7240-41b3-8f0c-00a10ea69c93/entry"
> rel="edit"></link><link
> href="https://sdkdev.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/wikis/form/api/wiki/744ccaeb-e9af-434c-9fa6-78831fb94846/page/3b017473-2dbe-4920-85a2-bf908a8e1475/attachment/7780e11c-7240-41b3-8f0c-00a10ea69c93/media"
> rel="edit-media"></link><link
> href="https://sdkdev.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/wikis/form/anonymous/api/wiki/744ccaeb-e9af-434c-9fa6-78831fb94846/page/3b017473-2dbe-4920-85a2-bf908a8e1475/attachment/7780e11c-7240-41b3-8f0c-00a10ea69c93/media/NominalWorkItem-v1.png"
> rel="enclosure" type="image/png" title="NominalWorkItem-v1.png"
> length="107763"></link><category term="attachment"
> scheme="tag:ibm.com,2006:td/type"
> label="attachment"></category><summary
> type="text"></summary><td:documentUuid>3b017473-2dbe-4920-85a2-bf908a8e1475</td:documentUuid><td:libraryId>744ccaeb-e9af-434c-9fa6-78831fb94846</td:libraryId><author><name>Frank
> Adams</name><snx:userid>6B54D23A-0A70-C7A4-8525-7CA50082A393</snx:userid><email>fadams@renovations.com</email><snx:userState>active</snx:userState></author><td:modifier><name>Frank
> Adams</name><snx:userid>6B54D23A-0A70-C7A4-8525-7CA50082A393</snx:userid><email>fadams@renovations.com</email><snx:userState>active</snx:userState></td:modifier><title
> type="text">NominalWorkItem-v1.png</title><published>2014-09-29T20:29:16.210Z</published><updated>2014-09-29T20:29:16.210Z</updated><td:created>2014-09-29T20:29:16.210Z</td:created><td:modified>2014-09-29T20:29:16.210Z</td:modified><td:lastAccessed></td:lastAccessed><content
> type="image/png"
> src="https://sdkdev.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/wikis/form/api/wiki/744ccaeb-e9af-434c-9fa6-78831fb94846/page/3b017473-2dbe-4920-85a2-bf908a8e1475/attachment/7780e11c-7240-41b3-8f0c-00a10ea69c93/media"></content></entry>
```

Comment: Works a treat, but I had to make a small change for authentication. Where you have `httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", auth.replace("=", ""));`, I changed it to `httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", auth);`. I kept getting a HTTP 401 response until I made that change.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible to do this with a multi-part post, but in my own code I'm doing it in steps:

1. **POST the XML-Atom entry:**

**Url:**

```
https://<Server>/<Wikis-Context-Root>/basic/api/wiki/<wikiUuid>/page/<pageUuid>/feed
```

**Content:**

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:td="urn:ibm.com/td">
    <category label="attachment" scheme="tag:ibm.com,2006:td/type" term="attachment"/>
    <td:label>file_name.extension</td:label>
</entry>
```

**Headers:**

```
Content-Type: <file mime-type, e.g. IMAGE/JPG>
Slug: <file_name.extension>
```

Response: 201; Location: URL to attachment entry

2. **PUT the attachment content**

**Url:** Location Response-Header of previous response, only exchange the last "/entry" for "/media"

**Content:** File-content stream

**Headers:**

```
Content-Type: <Mime-Type>
```

Response: 200 or 201

3. Optional: **PUT a description for the file**

**Url:** Location Response-Header of request from 1.)

**Content:**

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:td="urn:ibm.com/td">
    <category label="attachment" scheme="tag:ibm.com,2006:td/type" term="attachment"/>
    <summary type="text">MY ATTACHMENT DESCRIPTION TEXT</summary>
    <td:label>file_name.extension</td:label>
</entry>
```

**Headers:**

```
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
```

Response: 200 or 201

Comment: Thanks for responding. It looks like your technique should work, but I haven't tried it as the code in Paul's answer was easier to implement and test, as well as having the support advantage because it came from IBM.